# Displaying name in input, but sending id to the back-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, typeahead.js

I am trying to extend simple form so I can use an input (not a selection, just a text input) to select the owner of an account.  I want to display the account owner's name in the form when I'm editing the form and send their uuid to the back-end when I submit the form.  I've already gotten a typeahead menu to work that display's users from the database by name, but I can't figure out how to send the uuid of one of them once they've been selected.

So far I've figured out that I'll need to do something like this

```
  = simple_for_for @account do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    = f.input :name
    = f.simple_fields_for @account.contact do |p|
      = p.input :name

    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: you probably want a select box with `options_for_select`. Can you post your current form where you want to add this feature?

Comment: What kind of library is handling the typeahead? You probably should reconsider using a select box, you can easily mimic the required behaviour with jQuery.chosen library or something... this way there's still a fallback to a normal select.

Comment: I'm using typeahead.js, I was hoping to use the input so I could also create new users in the form if the user isn't already in the db.

Comment: Also, there are a huge number of users, so I don't want to grab them all every time an admin wants to do something like this, ideally they'd just grab a subset.  Using a text box makes that whole process much smoother for them.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of showing a related record dropdown for simpleform is like this:

```
simple_form_for :main_model do |f|
  f.input :name
  f.association :relationship_name_to_related_model
  f.submit
end
```

This will automatically populate the select box with the name field of the related_model and have the ID as values.

If your columns do not match the standards, you can overrule the defaults like this:

```
f.association :relationship_name_to_related_model, label_method: :name_of_label_column, value_method: :name_of_id_column
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to use a selection though, just a text input, should have made that clear.  I've updated my question.

Comment: What kind of javascript library are you using for that? Because you should probably have a look at that, since this doesn't sound like a Rails question anymore!

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the solution I went with was to write a custom `SimpleForm` input that consists of a stripped display input (that is not sent to the back-end) and a hidden id input that is updated by JS when the display input changes and is the part sent to the back-end to update the model.